# Is there a difference between two same capacity RAM's from two different companies?

Tags: memory, performance

I don't want overclocking on RAM's.

Is there a difference in performance between two same capacity DDR3-1600 RAM's from two companies?

Is the extra 8-10 dollars worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latency numbers can matter *on motherboards that can handle the lower latencies*. Consult your motherboard manual and/or BIOS configuration menus to see which latencies it can support.